# Special merge dataframes

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes and I would like to merge these two dataframes in a special way.

```
Dataframe 1: SF
CustomerID  CaseID   Datetime 
1            1       09-09-2018 18:02:00
1            2       16-09-2018 09:06:00
2            3       18-09-2018 11:07:00

Dataframe 2: apps
CustomerID   Text                                 Datetime
1            Hello, I want to know..              09-09-2018 18:00:00
1            Thank you for your question,..       09-09-2018 18:05:00
1            Oke thank you                        10-09-2018 18:20:00
1            Hello, can you help me with...       16-09-2018 09:05:00
1            Yes,....                             16-09-2018 09:10:00
2            Hi, where can I find....             18-09-2018 11:06:00
2            Hi, you can find it...               18-09-2018 11:09:00
2            Thanks!                              18-09-2018 11:15:00
```

The common ID between the two dataframes is CustomerID. But I want to merge the text messages to the right CaseID, so that I get the following result:

```
Dataframe 3: combined
CustomerID   Text                                Datetime             CaseID
1            Hello, I want to know..             09-09-2018 18:00:00  1
1            Thank you for your question,..      09-09-2018 18:05:00  1
1            Oke thank you                       10-09-2018 18:20:00  1
1            Hello, can you help me with...      16-09-2018 09:05:00  2
1            Yes,....                            16-09-2018 09:10:00  2
2            Hi, where can I find....            18-09-2018 11:06:00  3
2            Hi, you can find it...              18-09-2018 11:09:00  3
2            Thanks!                             18-09-2018 11:15:00  3
```

I think you can do this as follows (pseudocode):
For every caseID of a CustomerID take all text messages from the dataframe apps until the date of the next CaseID of that CustomerID. But I don't know how to write this in python code.

I Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried to far, and what issue(s) you are experiencing with that code.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems like you want to check if a certain date appears two dates based on the SF dataframe that you showed. However, it surprises me that:

```
1            Hello, can you help me with...      16-09-2018 09:05:00  2
```

Actually has case_id 2 when the date lies between case_id 1 and 2. If that's what you are looking for, then the following could help. First I recreated your dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrames as in example
sf_dates = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in 
            ['09-09-2018 18:02:00', '16-09-2018 09:06:00', '18-09-2018 11:07:00']]
apps_date = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in 
             ['09-09-2018 18:00:00', '09-09-2018 18:05:00', '09-10-2018 18:20:00', 
             '16-09-2018 09:05:00', '16-09-2018 09:10:00', '18-09-2018 11:06:00', 
             '18-09-2018 11:09:00','18-09-2018 11:15:00']]
apps = pd.DataFrame({'date':apps_date, 'customer_id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
case = pd.DataFrame({'date':sf_dates, 'case_id':[1, 2, 3]})
```

I then identified the first edge case, namely you want case_id 1 for all dates up to case_id 2:

```
edge_case_1 = (case.iloc[case.date.idxmin()].case_id,
case.iloc[case.date.idxmin()+1].date)
```

Edge case 2 is that you want case_id 3 for all dates after case_id 3:

```
edge_case_2 = (case.iloc[case.date.idxmax()].case_id, case.iloc[case.date.idxmax()].date)
```

Then, to construct a dictionary that for each case_id that is left over creates a start and end date to indicate between which two dates a certain case_id should be:

```
date_ranges = {case.loc[x, 'case_id']: (case.iloc[x].date, case.iloc[x+1].date) 
             for x in range(1, len(case)-1)}
```

Finally, apply it to the dataframe using apply:

```
def return_case_id(row, date_ranges, edge_case_1, edge_case_2):
    # Check for edge case 1
    if row.date < edge_case_1[1]:
        return edge_case_1[0]
    # Check for edge case 2
    elif row.date > edge_case_2[1]:
        return edge_case_2[0]
    # Check for all other cases (between two dates)
    else:
        for case_id, dates in date_ranges.items():
            if (row.date > dates[0]) & (row.date < dates[1]):
                return case_id

    # To check if everything happened as supposed to
    return

apps['case_id'] = apps.apply(lambda row: return_case_id(row, date_ranges, 
                                                    edge_case_1,
                                                    edge_case_2), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, for your answer Maarten. But that is not exactly what I meant.
I have now done it the following way and it works fine. Except ! have two problems:
1. It's very slow (has to do it for apps data with 20k records)
2. I stuck when I try to make a function of it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrames as in example
sf_dates = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in 
            ['09-09-2018 18:00:00', '16-09-2018 09:05:00', '18-09-2018 11:10:00']]
apps_date = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in 
             ['09-09-2018 18:00:00', '09-09-2018 18:05:00', '09-10-2018 18:20:00', 
             '16-09-2018 09:05:00', '16-09-2018 09:10:00', '18-09-2018 11:08:00', 
             '18-09-2018 11:09:00','18-09-2018 11:15:00', '22-09-2018 11:15:00']]
apps = pd.DataFrame({'date':apps_date, 'customer_id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,4]})
case = pd.DataFrame({'date':sf_dates, 'case_id':[1, 2, 3], 'customer_id':[1, 1, 2]})
```

Let's assign the case_id's to the apps data
    apps['case_id']=np.nan # Add a new empty column 'case_id' to the apps dataframe

```
for index_apps, row_apps in apps.iterrows(): # iterate over each row in apps data
    # make a new data set witch is a subselection of the case data, where     the customer_id is the same as the customer_id in the row of the apps     data
    case_selection = case[case.customer_id == row_apps['customer_id']] 
    case_selection = case_selection.reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index, so that index has successive numbers

index_case_selection=0
while index_case_selection>= 0:
    if case_selection.empty:
        # When the customer_id only exist in the apps dataframe and not in the case dataframe, then it isn't possible to assign a case_id to that app row.
        # so the case_id is NaN
            index_case_selection = -1
    elif (index_case_selection == (len(case_selection.index))-1) and (apps.date[index_apps] >= case_selection.date[index_case_selection]): 
            #when the iteration is at the last row (or the first row if there's only one) of the case_selection dataframe and date of the apps dataframe is bigger or equal than the date of the case_selection
            # then assign that casenumber to the apps dataframe
            apps.case_id[index_apps] = case_selection.case_id[index_case_selection]     
            index_case_selection = -1
    elif (index_case_selection == (len(case_selection.index))-1): 
            #when the iteration is at the last row (or the first row if there's only one) of the case_selection dataframe and date of the apps dataframe is smaller than the date of the case_selection,
            # then it isn't possible to assign a case_id to that app row. So the case_id is NaN
            index_case_selection = -1
    elif (apps.date[index_apps] >= case_selection.date[index_case_selection]) and (apps.date[index_apps] < case_selection.date[index_case_selection+1]):
            #when apps date is equal or bigger than the case_selection date and lower than the case_selection date 
            apps.case_id[index_apps] = case_selection.case_id[index_case_selection]             
            index_case_selection = -1
    else:
            index_case_selection += 1
```